# python3 HTTPServer/BaseHTTPRequestHandler output stream issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, basehttpserver, basehttprequesthandler

I have faced an issue with a built-in python3 http.server module. Specifically, wfile.write() method in BaseHTTPRequestHandler class.

I'm trying to send an html form pre-defined as a string to a client with a GET request. The output stream to the client is encoded as bytes-like object and transferred to the client.

However, on the client side when the server is started it's not rendered as html form. It ends up wrapped into `<pre>` tag and displayed as a preformatted text.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

form = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
  <title>Message Board</title>
  <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/">
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Post it!</button>
  </form>'''

class MessageHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(form.encode())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_address = ('', 8000)
    httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, MessageHandler)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I simply forgot to update `'Content-type'` header in GET response method

```
self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
```